# Flyway seems to not be overriding properties

Tags: windows, flyway

I have my standard flyway config in my pom file and I am trying to override in through system properties, as mentioned [here](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/).

Here is my configuration in the pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>dbUrl</url>
        <user>dbUser</user>
        <password>dbPass</password>
        <schemas>
            <schema>core</schema>
            <schema>public</schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And following is the command line that I'm running:

```
mvn clean compile flyway:migrate -Dflyway.url=anotherDbUrl -Dflyway.user=anotherDbUser -Dflyway.password=anotherDbPass
```

The documentation in the above link says `System properties > Maven properties > Plugin configuration`. Am I missing something?

Comment: please add the error you got :)

Comment: @mebala no error, it just execute with the settings in the pom file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch. This seems to have broken along the way. Could you please file an issue? I'll fix this in time for 2.2.1.